# How do I install GnuPG 2.1 in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, gnupg

Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 and later have GnuPG version 2.1 and higher in the main repository. I cannot upgrade my machine to Xenial yet, I am still stuck with Trusty for now.

How can I have GnuPG 2.1 installed in Trusty? And continue to receive updates for it as they are released?

Comment: I had an answer that involved apt pinning, which worked to upgrade GnuPG but then somehow meant I was no longer able to log in to a Unity graphical session. I had no problem with logging in on a tty terminal session, but Unity would not load at all. I suspect the apt errors were the problem, I'll keep investigating.